# ¿Como imprimir de forma correcta los datos de una consulta?

Tags: php, html, html5, css3

Buenas resulta que yo tengo una tabla (creada con divs) en la que quiero que vayan los resultados, seria como esta[image: imagen de la tabla correctamente] y se me están imprimiendo los resultados por toda la pantalla de esta forma. Solo el primero que es el de "0" se esta imprimiendo correctamente, el resto todos descolocados por la pantalla.  Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
    <div id="table" style="display: none;">

            <div class="table">
                <div><span>TITULO</span></div>
                <div><span>OPCIONES</span></div>
                <?php include('php/generartablalink.php')?>
     </div>          
    </div>
```

y en el php los estoy imprimiendo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esta es como salen:
[image: imagen de como salen]

GRACIAS POR VUESTRO TIEMPO

Comment: No pases código en imagenes, y si la llamada es a `generartablalink.php`, es o de la imagen es todo el código ??

Comment: Por otro lado, falta el css de el codigo tambien

Answer (score 0):

Para responder a tu pregunta: la forma correcta de imprimir datos de una consulta (o de cualquier otra fuente), es iterar sobre el conjunto de datos y escapar cada uno de los valores que serán puestos en el html resultante.

Básicamente esto

```
foreach($datos as $dato) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($dato['algo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Ahora, permíteme hacerte un par de sugerencias con respecto de tu código

1. Usa tablas en vez de divs. Las tablas han sido mal juzgadas por el uso abusivo de estas para el diseño en el pasado. Pero las tablas tienen su razón y esta es: mostrar datos.
2. Separa la lógica de negocio de la presentación. Esto es, no mezcles lógica en tus plantillas, pasa solo datos y luego la plantilla sabrá desplegar estos datos. Para esto sirven los motores de plantillas: twig, smarty, blade, raintpl, etc., etc.
3. Tu código no funciona porque tienes html mal formado en generartablalink.php y además el div que contiene la tabla tiene un display: none. Aveces podemos pasar horas resolviendo este tipo de problemas solo por no separar la lógica de negocio de la presentación.
4. También puedo ver que tienes un error en el bucle. Primero evalúas que $datos tenga un valor válido. Esto es un error porque a menos que hayas puesto algo en $datos directamente, esta condición no se cumple jamás. Debajo te dejo la forma correcta.
5. Aunque no es recomendable usar divs para esto, bien puedes usarlos aplicando estilos correctamente.

Te muestro un ejemplo que te puede servir

Archivo reporte.php

```
<?php

// en este archivo buscas los datos de la tabla
// y luego pasas esos datos a la plantilla
// como la plantilla es incluida con "include" 
// $datos es una variable válida en plantilla_de_reporte.php
$datos = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $datos[] = $row;
}

include 'plantilla_de_reporte.php';
```

Archivo plantilla_de_reporte.php

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>TÍTULO</td>
        <td>OPCIONES</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($datos as $dato): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($dato['titulo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td>
                <button>EDITAR</button>
                <button>ELIMINAR</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Archivo plantilla_de_reporte.php usando divs

```
<style>
    .table {
    }
    
    .row {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .column {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">TÍTULO</div>
        <div class="column">OPCIONES</div>
    </div>
    <?php foreach ($datos as $dato): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($dato['titulo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></div>
            <div class="column">
                <button>EDITAR</button>
                <button>ELIMINAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Como ves usar siempre  es incómodo y ensucia el código. Los motores de plantillas, como smarty, hacen esto de forma automática. Te recomiendo que tomes un rato para experimentar con ellos.

Espero esto te ayude. Buena suerte!